# JRuby and Weblogic 12.2.1.4 compatibility issues

Tags: java, ruby, jar, weblogic, jruby

When i deploy a war with JRuby 9.4.0.0 on Weblogic **12.2.1.4** i get the following error:

> resetting rack response due exception: org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: No such file or directory - C:/logs/oracle/wls/app/app.log from org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1255:in 'sysopen' from org/jruby/RubyFile.java:362:in 'initialize' from org/jruby/RubyClass.java:931:in 'new' from org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1174:in 'open' from...

Is it a problem of compatibility between jar files? It works with JRuby 1.7.4 and Weblogic 12.1.3.

Versions in **Gemfile**:

```
ruby '3.1.0'

#hardcoded version for Weblogic joda-time bug
gem 'jruby-jars', '1.7.4'
```

**Jar Files** in my *WEB-INF/lib* folder:

- jruby-complete-9.4.0.0.jar
- jruby-rack-1.1.22.jar
- kryptcore.jar
- kryptproviderjdk.jar
- ojdbc6.jar

I **removed** the following jars, moving from Weblogic 12.1.3 (it works with this old version of the server):

- jruby-rack-1.1.14
- jruby-core-1.7.4
- bcprov-jdk15on-1.47
- bcpkix-jdk15on-1.47
- jopenssl

Because of issues with bouncycastle (bcprov and bcpkix jars), and i added *jruby-complete* that should include *jruby-core* and *jopenssl* libs.

Comment: The `gem 'jruby-jars', '1.7.4'` looks just wrong to me, if you're trying to run JRuby 9.4. But I have no idea if the error you're getting has anything to do with that. (Also, as a tangential warning, I'd recommend either sticking with JRuby 9.3.9.0 for now or waiting for 9.4.1.0, which should fix a bunch of bugs still present in 9.4.0.0 such as random ArgumentErrors due to [a JIT bug](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/commit/129bd6312839fed1e7054af22607bbcd09b8ec21).)